# Inline style in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I want to show the follwing as Request History at one end and on same line label and drop down at other end

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="padding-bottom:20px">
        <apex:outputText style="font-weight:bold;float:left" value="REQUEST HISTORY" />
        <div style="float:right">
        <apex:outputLabel value="Showing: " for="Request" />
        <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1" id="Request" style="float:right">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Items}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!processRequests}"  rerender="pbtApplication"/>               
        </apex:selectList>
        </div>   
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

Output is: -- dropdown is shown first and then label..
It should ideally show a output label and then a drop down. What am i missing out here.

Als tried giving

```
<apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1" id="Request" style="float:right">
```

But no success as Label is overlapping with dropdown list.

Getting output as this 
[image]

Comment: try this..
<div style="float:left">

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `float:right;` from the `selectList`. You can remove `float: left;` from the `REQUEST HISTORY` too. Then it must work and looks like this:

[image]

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="padding-bottom:20px; width:300px;">
        <apex:outputText style="font-weight:bold;" value="REQUEST HISTORY" />
        <div style="float:right">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Showing: " for="Request" />
            <apex:selectList value="{!filter1}" size="1" id="Request">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Items}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="pbtApplication"/>               
            </apex:selectList>
        </div>   
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Its not working out for my code...the showing text is overlapping with dropdown list

Comment: @TestNS Have you tried my code?

Comment: @TestNS Then the problem is with another wrapper pannel or custom CSS classes. Could you post more VF code? (pls. just update your question)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following CSS `(inline-block)`

```
<apex:outputLabel value="Showing: " for="Request" style="display:inline-block" />
        <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1" id="Request" style="display:inline-block">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!Items}"/>
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!processRequests}"  rerender="pbtApplication"/>               
        </apex:selectList>
```